# Remove duplicate object in array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects of which I am trying to remove the duplicate elements from.

BUT with a condition. I only want to remove the ones where `title` === `title`

If it does equal `title`, then it should remove the object without the `taggedPosts` property

[image: example-structure]

End result would look like this

[image: final-result]

I've tried a lot of ways, but they all seem to only return the ones without the `taggedPosts` property and remove the ones with that property which is not what I want. Particularly `_.uniq(array)` from lodash.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the `_.remove` function from lodash instead.

For each element, check if a dupe exists and remove that element if it does not have the `taggedPosts` property.

```js
const data = [
  {title: '1', taggedPosts: []},
  {title: '2', taggedPosts: []},
  {title: '3', taggedPosts: []},
  {title: '4', taggedPosts: []},
  {title: '1'},
  {title: '5'},
  {title: '3'},
  {title: '6'},
];

_.remove(data, e => {
  // Search for a potential duplicate
  const dupe = data.find(d => d.title === e.title && d !== e);
  
  // Remove it if there is a duplicate and the current element does not have taggedPosts
  return dupe && !e.taggedPosts;
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Note: [remove](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove) modifies the array in place.

Comment: I've literally been stuck on this for so long now. Thank you so much! I had tried _.remove(array, object) but it wasn't working, or it was slicing the object at the wrong index. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vanilla javascript way

for each object in the array, we are looking for another object with same title and taggedPosts, if yes, we filter out the current object.

```
data.filter((item, index) => !data.find((innerItem, innInd) => innerItem.title === item.title && innerItem.taggedPosts  && index !== innInd))
```